# personalized monotonically_increasing_id spark

Tags: apache-spark, uuid

I have several dataframes and I want to uniquely identify each row in each dataframe. Hence I want to use personalized Ids . 
I am using the monotonically_increasing_id() built-in function in spark as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val dfWithId = trzuCom.withColumn("UniqueID", monotonically_increasing_id)
```

The problem is when I try to personalize it as follows :

```
val dfWithId = trzuCom.withColumn("UniqueID", "TB1_" + monotonically_increasing_id)
```

I get errors. 
Actually I want to have TB1_ID for dataframe 1, TB2_ID and so one . Any I dea how to do this please. 
Best Regards

Comment: In other words `trzuCom.withColumn("UniqueID", concat(lit("TB1_"),  monotonically_increasing_id))`.